# Git: restore a deleted branch. (i can find a commit within that branch with `git log -p SHA`)

Tags: git, git-log, recover

I deleted a branch that i want to restore.
I tried to recover it and the only thing i could find is a commit from `git-log` running:
`git log -p 4afa3abc4218b6251dea24c910eaced6af465d11`. Also - it seems that this SHA appears only on my local mac (when my colleague run this git-log command he gets an error)

I can see the changes in the output and i would like to create a brand new branch from this git log output.

How can i easily do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+create+branch+from+commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check out the commit and create the branch.

```
git checkout 4afa3abc4218b6251dea24c910eaced6af465d11
git branch yourbranch
```

Comment: Perhaps `git checkout -b yourbranch 4afa3abc4218` so that you are on the branch and not in detached HEAD state.